# ffmpeg jpg frame capture - How to discard corrupted frames

Tags: ffmpeg, jpeg, video-processing, corruption

I'm using ffmpeg 2.2.2 (Windows) to export a live camera stream into JPG frames.  I'm using the command line:

```
ffmpeg -err_detect aggressive -i rtsp://[ip address]:554/11 -r 1 -s 640x320 -an -f image2 c:\temp\snapshots\snapshot-%03d.jpg
```

This starts a continuous process which exports approximately 1 frame per second from the live stream.  However, at various times during the export, ffmpeg throws errors like this:

```
[h264 @ 00037ae0] RTP: missed 2 packets=00:01:09.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=1186
[h264 @ 02fbc340] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 02fbc340] concealing 4386 DC, 4386 AC, 4386 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 00037ae0] RTP: missed 13 packets
[h264 @ 02fbf7a0] left block unavailable for requested intra mode at 0 15p=1196
[h264 @ 02fbf7a0] error while decoding MB 0 15, bytestream 128288
[h264 @ 02fbf7a0] concealing 6409 DC, 6409 AC, 6409 MV errors in I frame
```

However, it proceeds to create a jpg file that is corrupted.  For example, the top of the file is fine, but then the same pixels smear down the rest of the image. Here's an example:
[image]

How can I force ffmpeg to either 1) discard these corrupt images after saving, or 2) simply "don't write" the image to a file after an error like this occurs?

I thought the err_detect flag may help, but it seems to make no difference.

Answer (score 12):

You can try the [discardcorrupt](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#Format-Options) flag on the input. The full command-line would be:

```
ffmpeg -err_detect aggressive -fflags discardcorrupt -i rtsp://[ip address]:554/11 -r 1 -s 640x320 -an -f image2 c:\temp\snapshots\snapshot-%03d.jpg
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 3):

I have reliably fixed this problem by forcing `ffmpeg` to use `tcp` instead of `udp`. Your command would look this way:

adding `-rtsp_transport tcp`:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://<ip_camera_url> -r 1 -s 640x320 -an -f image2 c:\temp\snapshots\snapshot-%03d.jpg
```

Comment: hi i go `Option rtsp_transport not found.`

Comment: This seems to help a little but not entirely. I still get corrupt frames.